# Asignar referencia a componente App para acceder desde el componente Root

Tags: vue.js

Tengo la siguiente duda, espero puedan ayudarme

¿Es posible asignar un `ref` a un componente mediante una *Función de renderizado*?, la cuestion es que tengo un proyecto en **Vue 2**, con la estructura que me da **Vue CLI** por defecto, lo cual me da algo como esto

```js
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
  data: {
    //
  }
```

Lo que entiendo que hace que se renderize el componente App:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">

  </div>
</template>
```

¿Como podría otorgarle una `ref` o referencia a este componente `App` para poder acceder a sus propiedades y métodos desde el `Root` componente?, ya que requiero llamar a cierto método cuando hayan ciertos cambios en el `Root`.

Aquí adjunto la estructura de componentes:

[image: estructura de componentes]

Espero haberme explicado bien, saludos

Comment: No se entiende... quien seria root? porque querrias acceder a metodos fuera de tu componente actual? tal vez si explicas porque queres hacer eso, se te pueda dar una respeusta...

Comment: Vale ya edito la pregunta colocando una estructura de los componentes amigo

Comment: mas que la estructura, que queres hacer?

Comment: Ya te explico amigo

Comment: Lo que pasa, es que en `Root` tengo lo que se conoce como modelo de tienda, ya que no uso **Vuex** en este proyecto, y allí se almacenan los mensajes del chat, por ende también los métodos que traen los mensajes desde la API. lo que quiero hacer es que al traer nuevos mensajes se llame a un metodo que tengo en el componente `Chat` que baja el Scroll al final de ese `div`

Comment: El componente `Chat`, esta contenido dentro de `App` por eso quiero llamar a un método dentro de `App` que a su vez llama a ese metodo dentro de `Chat` que lleva el scroll hasta el final

Comment: ok.. no tengo ni idea como solucionar tu problema.. toda esa explicacion deberia estar en la pregunta..y yo no se, porque para evitar todas esas cosas es que esta vuex...

Comment: @gbianchi si, considerare usar **Vuex**, de igual manera seguiré explorando soluciones, muchas gracias

Comment: Ojo.. igual vos fijate que un componente como axios, vos lo podes aplicar al root para poder usar... asi que tranquilamente podrias hacer lo mismo con cualquier componente....

Comment: A simple vista no entiendo en que momento te parás en tu componente Root para llamar a App. Lo normal es que App sea el Root de nuestra aplicación, no? Te recomiendo que sigas los consejos de gbianchi. Vue3 tiene unas funciones llamadas provide e inject que facilitan muchisimo la comunicación entre componentes. Con vue2 lo mejor que podes hacer es instalar vuex, no vas a perder mucho tiempo. Las propiedades que necesitas compartir las metes en la tienda, y desde ahi es muy simple llamar a los watchers para que observen cambios, podrias hacer lo que queres pero desde cualquier componente.

Comment: No obstante, en la documentación se aclara que lo que vos querés hacer es posible, agregar el atributo ref en la llamada al componente (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html) pero insisto, si estás en vue2, lo mejor es que entiendas como manejarte con vuex. No es nada complicado y facilita la comunicacion entre componentes.

Comment: @AgustinG. si, estoy usando Vue 2, por lo cual me decidí a meter Vuex, ya que es necesario, al principio solo me bastaba con el sencillo modelo de tienda en el Root pero el proyecto fue creciendo poco a poco jaja. Muchas gracias amigo